# Does maven dependecyManagement impact pluginManagement transitive dependencies?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin, dependency-management, parent-pom

I understand that `<dependencyManagement>` config impacts to `<dependencies>` and transitive dependencies there. But also affects plugins under `<pluginManagement>` or `<plugins>`?

I have a case where is not happening, but just want to confirm if is a general behavior or something is wrong in my config.

Let's say that I need to use `the-plugin`, that has as dependency `dep-a:1.0`.
But I need to make that `the-plugin` uses `dep-a:1.1` instead.

Is the following pom correctly configured to achieve this?

```
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>group-a</groupId>
                <artifactId>dep-a</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>group-plugin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>the-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

I tested the above pom but is not working, I had to do the following to make it work as I need. Is this the correct configuration?

```
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>group-a</groupId>
                <artifactId>dep-a</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>group-plugin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>the-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>group-a</groupId>
                            <artifactId>dep-a</artifactId>
                            <version>1.1</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

Comment: I don't think dependencyManagement has any influence on plugins, and it would cause weird side effects if it does. It is not unusual to allow "dangerous" dependencies in the plugins, but not for the app itself because the plugins only run on your own build server. But I have not checked the actual code, nor do I have a source in the docs.

Comment: Why does the plugin need a different version of such dependency? And why does a project use the same dependency as a plugin? Can you give more details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dependencyManagement is intended for dependencies of your project and **NOT** for dependencies of plugins. These are two different things.

In other words the given dependencyManagement can not influence the dependency of a plugin.

If a plugin needs a different version there are the following options:

- You have to give the dependency explicit as already shown.
- You have to upgrade the plugin version which contains the needed (newer?) version
- The plugin will handle that automatically and uses the version which is given via the dependencies of the project (which has a number of impacts).